# How VirtualProtect change memory protection flag

Tags: windows

The 3rd parameter of VirtualProtect can use flags as follow:

```
PAGE_EXECUTE
PAGE_NOACCESS
PAGE_READWRITE
PAGE_READONLY
```

...

At the first I think VirtualProtect may achieve it by using PTE's flag. But when I read the structure of PTE, I cannot find the flag in PTE which record this function's 3rd parameter.

The PTE's structure as follow:

Sorry i cannot post images (*for don't have 10 reputation!* ), you can find it from Google.

I want to find where the Windows record the protection flag of a virtual memory page, Is not  PTE？

After read some material, I Noticed that when a PTE is invalid, the meaning of PTE's fields have changed! And then have 5-bits for protection flag.

Comment: The details are architecture specific. Read the docs for each architecture that you are interested in. For instance, for Intel architectures it's in vol 3, chapter 4.6 access rights.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,Thinks at first, but I just found read/write flag and user/supervisor flag.Is anyting I missed?

Comment: I don't know. What do you think is missing?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I mean whether some reserved flags in PTE's structure may be used by OS for record the data.

Comment: The NX flag, probably, No eXecute.  Added later.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I will do some tests when I find a way to get PTE of a memory page and observe it after call the protect function.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, but the NX flag just used in x64 from book " windows Internals" says. And it still cann't explain PAGE_NOACCESS flag.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan，Not long ago I have wrote a page memory allocator for detect wild pointer. I just read Windows API and did it, and now I want find how the OS did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available ProtectionFlags are a super-set of what an Intel processor supports.  Keep in mind that Windows was written to run on a variety of processors, it once supported MIPS, Itanium, Alpha and PowerPC as well.  A mere footnote today, AMD/Intel won by a landslide with ARM popular on mobile devices.

An Intel processor has pretty limited support for the page protection attributes.  A page table entry has:

- bit 1 for (R/W), a 1 allows write access, a 0 only allows read access
- bit 2 for (U/S), user/supervisory, not relevant to user mode code
- bit 63 for (XD), eXecute Disabled.  A late addition to AMD cores, originally marketed as "Enhanced Virus Protection", adopted by Intel.  All processors you'll find today support it.

So the kernel maps the protection flags like this:

- PAGE_NOACCESS: the page simply won't be mapped to RAM
- PAGE_READONLY: R/W = 0, XD = 1
- PAGE_READWRITE: R/W = 1, XD = 1
- PAGE_EXECUTE: R/W = 0, XD = 0

Comment: Thanks！And in your opinion, these flags such as PAGE_NOACCESS, PAGE_GUARD, PAGE_WRITECOPY(except PAGE_READONLY, PAGE_READWRITE, PAGE_EXECUTE) are just supported by OS (not processor)? and are not recorded in page table entry?

Comment: That's correct, they affect what the memory manager does, not the processor.

Comment: Thinks again! I just think that OS can totally provide all the flags by itself, because OS has controled how a virtual address map to a physical address! If my opinion is right, and then another question: why OS need processor's support?

Comment: No, a basic test like write access has to be implemented by the processor.  Trying to do that in the OS would be drastically unpractical.  The XD option got added because the OS check wasn't reliable enough.

Comment: Thinks for your answer again!